# Select a value one by one to Insert into Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

I am trying to create a Insert Statement with an Selete Statement to get a value, that value is stored in a variable. That Value is used in Insert Statement. Now I would like to do is get the value from the select statement one by one and Insert it into the table.

```
  DECLARE @value INT=
    (
        SELECT ID
        FROM PageContent
        WHERE PageNo = 2
              AND ID NOT IN
        (
            SELECT ID
            FROM answers
        )
    );
    DECLARE @Postid INT =
    (
        SELECT MAX(Postid) + 1
        FROM ContentPost
    );
    INSERT INTO ContentPost
    (Postid,  ID,  text,  ordernuber,  insertDate )
    VALUES
    (@Postid,  @value,  'ABC',  1,  GETDATE()),
(@Postid,  @value,  'DEF',  2,  GETDATE()),
(@Postid,  @value,  'GHI',  3,  GETDATE()),
(@Postid,  @value,  'JKL',  4,  GETDATE());
```

Note: @Value will be same same for all insert values statement.

I need help in improving **DECLARE @value** part to get the value one by one.

Comment: `@answerid` is not declared, so you will get an error for that. I think you meant that to be `@Postid`.

Comment: You may need a cursor for this to do 1 by 1. Although some people frown on cursors, so a While loop might be the way to go.

Comment: Two big red flags here, I assume you should be able to join PageContent to ContentPost on (some value). This would allow you to handle this in one query instead of multiple with variables. And two, you are calculating the next post ID to insert into the ContentPost table. A better practice would be to have that column be IDENTITY and increment the value automatically.

Comment: @JacobH you didn't get that ID from PageContent is added to ContentPost to check where to put the content from ContentPost based on that site is populated. So ID from PageContent is Identity but I have to add that to ContentPost Table to fetch the text for that specific ID. PageContent contains Header for that text and ContentPost contains text under neath the Header

Comment: @WEI_DBA Can you please elaborate how do I use for this?

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here but certainly doing row by agonizing row is entirely the wrong idea. Looping in t-sql is horribly inefficient when a single insert statement will work. I would suggest looking for a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SeanLange What is not Clear? I have two Tables PageContent and ContentPost. Basically I have a site which is fully populated by database. PageContent contains Header take it as Question and ContentPost contains text take it as answer which should be post below that Header (Question). Lets take a dropdown box each dropdown box contains answer which I am inserting in ContentPost.

Comment: Yes I get that you have two tables like that. You obviously need some help with your code which I can help with. But I can't see your screen, I don't know what your table structures are like, I don't know what your data is or what process you are trying to accomplish.